Excel formula to extract alphanumeric string and subtract 1 from the numeric portion
I would like to find a formula that would make the number portion of an alphanumeric string minus one.  Is it possible to do it in one formula or must it be done with two separate formulas?
Example:     
Original string:   P300,
Formula makes it:  P299,

Unable to make it work in one formula, can only make it with 2 separate formulas:
=MID(B2,2,3)-1
="P"&G2&","

Note:  sometimes it is P that precedes the number and sometimes it is R.

What determines P and R?

The original cell location from the worksheet.  I have a column that lists the cell addresses - some start with P and some start with R.

=LEFT(B2)&MID(B2,2,3)-1

Or: =REPLACE(B2, 2, 3, MID(B2,2,3)-1)

Thanks very much to both of you!  Both seem to work - when I have a 2 digit cell like P37, then I just adjust the total characters to 2 and that works.

@GayleAlley don;t think you will need to change it will still work, in both formulas. and this is because we are explicitly stating the functions to start at position 2

Keeping your logic (even though @MayukhBhattacharya 's version is shorter): =LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)-1&","


This makes use of the sequence, textjoin, mid, len, and concatenate function. This will put all of the characters in the text into an array, join the numbers together turning them into a number, and then concatenates a P in front.

Naming cells ranges is very convenient - here with data cells named as range, we could use the following in any cell with enough empty rows below (otherwise you will get #SPILL error):
=LEFT(range) & MID(range, 2, LEN(range)-2) -1 & RIGHT(range)


